# How do I write my own HasInstance

Tags: c++, v8

I have a C++ object wrapped with a V8 object, as described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects). I want to check that a method receives this object as an argument. Standard V8 objects have a HasInstance method for that. How do I implement such a function myself? How can I make sure that the object I got is actually the required wrapped object?

Comment: self = holder->FindInstanceInPrototypeChain(function_template.Get(isolate)); <= something like that maybe?

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Thanks.